# Compiling Multi-File Project in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I have written a project for a friend in Visual Studio, containing bunch of `.h` and `.cpp` files. Now I want to compile my code in Turbo C++ and when I compile the main function the following error occurs:

> unable to open include file 'blah.h'

How can I compile my multi-file project in Turbo C++?

I haven't written a line in Turbo C++ in my life! So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While still in use in some schools in India, Turbo C++ is grossly outdated, so you should do your best in trying to stay away from it.

Comment: Why would you want to compile a new project on an 8 year old compiler? The last version of Turbo C++ is from 2006. The best thing to do is use another compiler. Preferably not the Embarcadero line (ex. Turbo/Borland) which is lagging behind current C++ compiler development by years and clearly just the unloved stepchild besides their Delphi compiler.

Comment: You are so right! I hate everything about it, but this project is for my friend for his programming course and the teacher won't accept the code in any other IDE (Don't ask why, I don't know either.)

Comment: "I have written a project for a friend" and "this project is for my friend for his programming course" - perhaps your friend should have done his own course-work?

Comment: Ehm... why not switch to something more up to date?

Comment: Can't you use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler?

Comment: @AmeMertz bcc64 is C++11-compliant

Answer (score 1):

From the **menubar**, select the **Project** menu, then **New Project**. The name you give the project in 'Project Path and Name' will by default be the name that the executable file will have. If you want a different name for the executable file, enter that name in the 'Target' field. By default the `.cpp` file with the same name will be added to the list of source files. In the example in the last section, if the project is given the name trial, then the executable file will be `trial.exe` and the source code file trial.cpp will automatically be included in the list of files to be compiled. Before pressing the OK button, you should select the 'Easywin' target option, and also press the 'Application Expert' button, and clear the check marks against the .def and `.rc` files. Once the project is set up, you can add other source files to the list of those that need to be compiled by either using the 'Add node' button (which has an icon, but no text), or by dragging the source file with the mouse from the ordinary Windows File Manager and releasing the mouse button over the representation of the target (in this case `trial.exe`) in the project.

For more information take a look at the following link: http://dybfin.wustl.edu/willard/turbohlp.html