# Conversion of header into cpp file using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have folder contain a Visual Studio project and contain lots of `.h` and `.cpp` file I want to put all of this .h and `.cpp` file into just one `main.cpp` file is there any way to do that with Visual Studio or any other things??

Comment: I don't believe so. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to compile this on turbo c++ and this IDE is really old  and can't compile multi-file :(

Comment: @Daniel.V: So compile it on an IDE that is _not_ twenty years old.

Comment: I have to actually my teacher one turbo c++ he is traditional man :(

Comment: `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`. Or `type *.h *.cpp > everything.cpp` (or however you do things in Windows) in the command window. Then fix the compilation errors.

Comment: @Daniel.V oh, and if you wrote any thing even remotely resembling *modern* C++ (say, any new features or changes in the last 10 - 15 years), it probably won't compile in Turbo C++.

Comment: @crashmstr you're time line is a bit too small. It's closer to 20 than 15.

Comment: @crashmstr, Even without changes, the traditional C++98 Hello World doesn't compile in Turbo.

Comment: @Daniel.V: Using Turbo C++ is about as far from "traditional" as you can get. Find a new teacher.

Comment: I can't believe I stuck just in compiling my project in turbo c++

Comment: @Daniel.V Are you sure Turbo C++ cannot compile multi-file projects, or are you too lazy to find out how to do it? It was a long time ago, but I used Turbo C (no ++) with multi-file projects.

Comment: I tried I really really tried and search about it I couldn't find any resource that can help me compile multi file in turbo c++

Comment: @anatolyg Do you know how to compile multi file in turbo c++ or any resource that can help me on this it would be great full

Comment: Interesting that this was asked just a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503242/compiling-multi-file-project-in-turbo-c

Comment: Yeah that my partner who help me on this project we both stuck on this silly project :(

Comment: You should follow the advice from that question then.  It's easy to create a project, and the road you're attempting to go down here is much worse.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this trivially. You would have to *refactor*, as merging source files can introduce semantic problems. It's best to not do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the functions and libraries you are using it can/can't be done. if all the functions are compilable in Turbo and the project isn't that professional which I think it isn't based on you saying you want it for your course project you can simply copy everything in a cpp and convert the header files into simple classes. anyway Turbo C++ is Dead!